# Appending Blob To Form Data Throws TypeError: source.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, blob, fetch-api, form-data

I am having a weird issue with appending a blob to FormData. According to the docs( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append ), the append function can either be a String or Blob. My code is as such:

```
const blobFromSync = (...args) =>
  import('node-fetch').then(({ blobFromSync }) => blobFromSync(...args));

let file_location = '/path/to/video/file.mp4';

const file = await  blobFromSync(file_location);

const chunkSize = 40000;

for (let start = 0; start < file.size; start += chunkSize) {
            const chunk = file.slice(start, start + chunkSize + 1)
            
            const form = new FormData();
           
            form.append('file', chunk, 'an-id');
}
```

Console logging the chunk shows it a Blob, but it throws this error:

```
TypeError: source.on is not a function
    at DelayedStream.create (/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Development/terminal-backend/node_modules/delayed-stream/lib/delayed_stream.js:33:10)
    at CombinedStream.append (/Users/xxxxxxx/Development/terminal-backend/node_modules/combined-stream/lib/combined_stream.js:45:37)
    at FormData.append (/Users/xxxxxxxxx/Development/terminal-backend/node_modules/form-data/lib/form_data.js:75:3)
    at /Users/xxxxxxxxxn/Development/terminal-backend/src/server.js:90:18
```

What am I overlooking here?

Comment: This seems like something further down the chain, maybe where the `form` is being consumed? It looks like something is expecting a stream, but not getting one.

Comment: @Matt It eventually is suppose to go in fetch as a POST request as a way of upload large files, but I've taken all of that out and the append function is all the code is doing.

Comment: I think MDN doc might be a bit outdated. The official github page of form-data says that the second argument should either be string, int, bool, buffer. https://github.com/form-data/form-data#void-append-string-field-mixed-value--mixed-options-.  So a `Buffer.from(<your blob>)` should work in your case.

Comment: @RahulSharma the MDN article is about the WHATWG FormData API, not about the npm library. It's not "outdated". But you're right [they don't support Blobs as input](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/529). FWIW, FormData is now [natively supported in node > 17](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#class-formdata) (even if still marked as experimental), just like fetch. If one isn't afraid of using experimental features, then there isn't even a need for a library anymore.

Comment: @RahulSharma Your answer of Buffer.from worked. My code is form.append('file', Buffer.from(await chunk.arrayBuffer()), event_id);. Put it as the answer I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The official documentation on MDN is related to WHATWG FormData API standards which says that `form.append` accepts `Blob` as the second argument. Beware that it's just a specification (not an implementation).

The implementation that you're using doesn't support `Blob` as highlighted in this [issue](https://github.com/form-data/form-data/issues/529). As also mentioned in the [doc](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#void-append-string-field-mixed-value--mixed-options-).

You can, however, create a `Buffer` out of your `Blob` using `Buffer.from(<blob>)` and it should work.

**P.S.**: Credits to @Kaiido for pointing out the WHATWG specification and finding the github issue.